# Backbone Syphon Nested Attributes

Tags: javascript, html, json, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following HTML in a form...

```
<input type="text" id="test1" name="steps[description]" value="one step">
<input type="text" id="test2" name="steps[description]" value="two step">
```

Im merely just trying to produce an array of objects like the following JSON

```
steps [ {description:"one step"}, {description:"two step"}]
```

However when i Backbone.Syphon parses the form, it always just produces one value (always the last occurance of the input field with that name) in the steps Array like below

```
steps [{description:"two step"}]
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax or is this not possible with Backbone.Syphon?

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try to name your inputs in the following way

```
<input type="text" id="test1" name="steps[][description]" value="one step">
<input type="text" id="test2" name="steps[][description]" value="two step">
```

Notice the extra `[]` that makes it an actual array of objects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've actually tried this syntax and a bunch of others. When i call `Backbone.Syphon.serialize(this)` and write out the serialized result to the console im still only getting the last input value as the only element in the array.

Comment: I have got very similer requirement, And this solution is not working for me. Any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Add index to the each similar input as well.

```
<input type="text" id="test1" name="steps[1][description]" value="one step">
<input type="text" id="test2" name="steps[2][description]" value="two step">
```

On form submit you can call the serializeObject function like this:

```
var data = $('#form' + formId).serializeObject();
this.model.save(data, {
    success : function(model) {
    },
    error : function(model) {
    }
});
```

You could use the serializeObject function below which will parse the above syntax. This is same as is solved in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
        var json, patterns, push_counters, _this = this;
        json = {};
        push_counters = {};
        patterns = {
            validate : /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?:\[(?:\d*|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\])*$/,
            key : /[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|(?=\[\])/g,
            push : /^$/,
            fixed : /^\d+$/,
            named : /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/
        };
        this.build = function(base, key, value) {
            base[key] = value;
            return base;
        };
        this.push_counter = function(key) {
            if(push_counters[key] ===
            void 0) {
                push_counters[key] = 0;
            }
            return push_counters[key]++;
        };
        $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, elem) {
            var k, keys, merge, re, reverse_key;
            if(!patterns.validate.test(elem.name)) {
                return;
            }
            keys = elem.name.match(patterns.key);
            merge = elem.value;
            reverse_key = elem.name;
            while(( k = keys.pop()) !==
            void 0) {
                if(patterns.push.test(k)) {
                    re = new RegExp("\\[" + k + "\\]$");
                    reverse_key = reverse_key.replace(re, '');
                    merge = _this.build([], _this.push_counter(reverse_key), merge);
                } else if(patterns.fixed.test(k)) {
                    merge = _this.build([], k, merge);
                } else if(patterns.named.test(k)) {
                    merge = _this.build({}, k, merge);
                }
            }
            return json = $.extend(true, json, merge);
        });
        return json;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We have used Backbone.Syphone to parse. So for consistency, adding custom code is not an option. I would really like if there is some way I can fix it using Backbone.Syphone only.

Comment: Backbone.Syphone seems to have an open [bug](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.syphon/issues/34) to solve this issue. I use the given function and it parses even complex array of objects or vice versa. It always helps to have minimal logic if it is simple, rather than using an external library.